# How do I write to system/ports/input?

Tags: cgi, rebol, rebol3

I can read from `system/ports/input` (for example CGI data), but how do I write to this port so I can read it using `read system/ports/input`?

`write system/ports/input some-data` returns error *cannot use write on port! value*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console scheme currently only supports a 'read actor.

See https://github.com/rebol/rebol/blob/master/src/core/p-console.c

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say

```
system/ports/output
```

as well, but I noticed that it is 'none in my r3.

On the other hand, just using

```
print "something"
```

should automatically use standard output, which is used b cgi as well.

Comment: I reformulated my question, I need to read the data back in Rebol also.